# how do i debug error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm compiling a .c program using gcc compiler on linux,

But , i received the error shown as "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

The error is due to the line of code as shown below

```
 (socklen_t*)saddr_size=*(data2.ssize);
```

May I know how to debug this problem ?

They are declared in the structure as

```
 struct fields{ 
     void* b;   
     struct sockaddr *s;
     socklen_t *ssize;

 }data2; 

 int saddr_size;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is nonsensical. Try

```
saddr_size = (int)(*data2.ssize);
```

But ... why is saddr_size declared int? Try

```
socklen_t saddr_size;
...
saddr_size = *data2.ssize;
```

I also wonder why ssize is a pointer, rather that the size itself.

Answer (score 1):

The left value you have cast it to a socklen_t * pointer type, however the right value is socklen_t type, so this error is printed. I have the same question as Jim Balter, you should make sure the socklen_t type can be expressed by int. I mean if int is 32 bytes, would socklen_t be more than 32 bytes?
You should declare saddr_size socklen_t type

Answer (score 0):

try changing it like

*(socklen_t*)&saddr_size=*(data2.ssize)

Comment: Not a good idea ... that's undefined behavior if `socklen_t` isn't a typedef for `int`, and will in practice will crash of they aren't the same size.

Answer (score 0):

In C, an lvalue is a "left" value, which means a token to which it is valid to assign a value. So the compiler is telling you that the token on the left side of an assignment expression is not valid.

Comment: No, it's saying that the *expression* on the left side is not assignable (there are 5 tokens on the left side here) ... and you haven't said how to fix it.